# What is the min score a randomly selected student should get to be top 5%?

Tags: r

I want to find what is the minimum score that a randomly selected student can get to be top 5% in the class?

Let’s suppose
we have **mean** and **sd**

Comment: Please give us some context to your question. Take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for hints. It's a good start to give some data, make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and give an example of your desired output.

Comment: Thanks Martin, unfortunately there is not any data, it is a question from normal distribution, it is a general question, where I have only mean and sd

Comment: In this case your question could include at least the terms "normal distribution". ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use **qnorm** function, if it says top 5% in the class,

```r
qnorm(0.95, mean = , sd = )
```

If you need any explanation, let me know!

Comment: Or `qnorm(0.05, mean = , sd = , lower.tail = FALSE)`